# Want to use mupdf for android app in our project

Tags: mupdf

I have downloaded muPdf source. we want to use in our android application for our company.. can I use the library and android source as reference for our application.

Please dont mind if I ask stupid question, because Im confused after reading the licencing information.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its open source code under the Affero General Public Licence. If your application or usage conforms to the AGPL then you can use the library freely.

If it does not (eg you intend to sell your application, or you intend to use portions of the source without making your own source open source under the AGPL) then you must seek a commercial licence. Artifex has a range of different licencing options, including one specifically designed for Android/iPhone app developers.

If you feel you need a commercial licence, or want to discuss it, then you should contact sales@artifex.com.